# How to deal with questions/answers with a security vulnerability?

Tags: feature-request, security

Sine a major goal of SO is to compile the best programming questions and answers on the internet, I'm wondering if there's more we can do to single out and/or correct cases where questions or answers contain exploitable code (see [MySQL Select Statement - GROUP BY/Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180956/mysql-select-statement-group-by-unique) which includes an sql injection vulnerability).
I always try to point this out to authors, but I tend not to make edits so I don't change "the meaning" of the author.

One approach for this I though of was to create a special flag to be added to questions or answers noting that the included code or advice is unsafe. Alternatively, is it better to follow a hard "edit out" approach in these cases?

Answer (score 6):

(For those of us who don't have edit rights)

In the case of your example, I think answering with your own safe code and stating that it is also not vulnerable to SQL injection.

When the vulnerable code is in an answer, post the code in a new answer, and leave a comment pointing to it.

Answer (score 5):

It is probably better to just edit the code and leave a note that you were making it SQL injection safe. Mainly because if we added a flag, some people would ignore it. Better to just make the code safe and risk someone not knowing exactly what its doing.