# How to handle questions with dangerous code (e.g. SQL injection) in Q and Answers?

Tags: discussion, code

A [question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108281/update-where-id-getid/14108325) contains PHP code (probably a wordpress plugin) that has classic SQL injection vulnerabilities. About half a dozen of answers copy&paste the code and fix the issue that caused the code not to work, without mentioning the SQL injection issue. If people later come upon the question and answers and decide to take it as an example, we will have even more insecure software around.

So, what is the correct way to handle it?

- put in an answer that warns about the issue?
- put in a comment that warns about the issue?
- flag the question?
- downvote the question?
- edit the question to include a warning?
- flag each answer that copy&pasted the code?
- comment on each answer that copy&pasted the code?
- downvote each answer that copy&pasted the code?

My main problem is that comments warning about the issue will not be easily noticed by visitors.

Comment: ill do this by providing answer like http://stackoverflow.com/a/14108644/1723893

Comment: This is totally a dupe, but I can't find it.  IIRC, the consensus was, in the limited case where the code in the *question* is broken and the answers copy/paste, it's *not* the responsibility of the people answering questions to fix the code.  It always helps, of course, and such answers should generally get upvoted.

Comment: There is a more recent dup than this one that I recall, but here's one: [Is there a policy on dangerous answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102536/182513)

Comment: And this isn't quite a dup, but related: [How to deal with highly voted answers with security vulnerabilities?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158741/182513)

Comment: SO exists to answer programmers' questions; not to save the world from SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the correct way to handle it?

Here is what I think:

> put in an answer that warns about the issue?

That would be great. Posting an answer that fixes OP's problem and also fixes the security issue separately

> put in a comment that warns about the issue?

If unable to post an answer then adding a comment is always a good idea

> flag the question?

An invalid flag if the post follows FAQ guidelines

> downvote the question?

No. If OP has spent time to explain the question and context properly then downvote is not warranted

> edit the question to include a warning?

No. I would term it as an invalid edit

> flag each answer that copy&pasted the code?

An invalid flag. Community made an effort to help the OP, if the answers are inline to the question then no flagging is not valid

> comment on each answer that copy&pasted the code?

Not a bad idea

> downvote each answer that copy&pasted the code?

No. Same point as mentioned above for downvoting the question

Comment: This is what I was afraid would be true - the correct course of action is the one that won't really help...

Comment: I guess it would help. Correct action in my view is to post an answer, so future visitors know what is good and what is bad (and if they agree they will upvote the answer which talks about security fixes too). So it helps in the long run. I appreciate your concern but remember we are not here to force others to beef up their security, we can only provide helpful pointers.

Comment: This doesn't really work. There are too many people that only read the answer, try it, think "it works" and upvote. They don't bother finding (usually slightly more complicated) solutions in other answers that aren't insecure. [Here's a classic example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7510399/265521). SQL Injection 101, but still the top voted answer.

Answer (score -2):

My take: if the vulnerability is relevant to the question being asked, address it in an answer. Otherwise, leave a comment and/or just edit it out yourself. Pointing it out in an answer would only serve as a distraction for future visitors.

Of course, on sites like [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), you should probably put it in the answer always.

Comment: Sure, an answer doesn't have to address every flaw in the OP's code, it just needs to address the OP's question. And if the code has multiple (semi-)independent flaws that the OP asks about then the question probably Needs Focus. OTOH, to post answer code the replicates actual security flaws from the OP's code is irresponsible, and undermines the trustworthiness of the Q&A library that we're trying to build on SO.

Comment: If the answerer won't fix it, and tries to prevent others from fixing it (which happens regularly), the answer should get a warning comment. In some ways, a comment is actually *better* than repairing the answer because the author can roll back edits, but can't remove comments. And I doubt a mod would remove a comment warning against a security flaw. FWIW, I consider answers containing SQL vulnerabilities to be Not Useful, even if they have solved the thing the OP asked about. So I have no qualms about downvoting and del-voting, if the author won't fix it, or allow it to be fixed.

Comment: @PM2Ring: fix the flaw *in the question* then, so that the answers will only have to address what was asked, and not any tangential issues.

Comment: And if the poster doesn’t respond well to their posts being edited, that’s a separate issue, and something they should adjust to anyway, as a general matter. If you want to discourage the poster from silently reverting your edit, you can post a comment explaining the edit *after* making it, and link to the diff; it will be quite awkward for them to revert the edit without addressing it at all.

Comment: They're both good points. However, changing the content of the OP's code in any way (apart from putting it into a code block) has issues too. Such edits are usually rejected as conflicting with the author's intent, (or for potentially editing the problem out of the question) and could partly invalidate any existing answers that do address the security flaw.

Comment: But I guess for security flaws that the OP doesn't mention it should be ok to add a new code block without the security flaw, so that both versions are visible. Or edit out the flaw but add an explicit link in the question body to the flawed version in the revision history, so it's obvious to future readers that there *was* a flaw.